# Is there an easy way to show that $F(z)=\sum_{j=1}^{z}\zeta(j+1)-\zeta(z+5)-z$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

### $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\zeta(2n+z)-2\zeta(n+z+1)+\zeta(n+z+2)-\zeta(n+z+3)+\zeta(2n+z+5)\right]=F(z)$$

### Is there is a simple way to show that ($z\ge0$) $$F(z)=\sum_{j=1}^{z}\zeta(j+1)-\zeta(z+5)-z$$

Comment: Where did you find it ?

Comment: from hard working, not from any site

Comment: Then, congratulations since it is remarkable !

Comment: R u sure? I checked it, it work fine

Comment: how do i open up a chat room?

Comment: discord or smth?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124244/discussion-between-sibawayh-and-bookwick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_n$ be a sequence such that $\sum_{0<n}f_n$ absolutely converge, then
\begin{align}
&\sum_{0<n}(f_{2n}-2f_{n+1}+f_{n+2}-f_{n+3}+f_{2n+5})\\
&=\sum_{0<n}(f_{2n}+f_{2n+5})-2\sum_{0<n}f_{n+1}+\sum_{0<n}(f_{n+2}-f_{n+3})\\
&=\sum_{0<n}(f_{2n}+f_{2n+1})-\sum_{0<n}(f_{2n+1}-f_{2n+5})-2\sum_{0<n}f_{n+1}-f_3\\
&=\sum_{0<n}f_{n+1}-(f_3+f_5)-2\sum_{0<n}f_{n+1}-f_3\\
&=-\sum_{0<n}f_{n+1}-f_5
\end{align}
Put $f_n=\zeta(n+z)-1$, we have
\begin{align}
F(z)&=\sum_{0<n}(\zeta(2n+z)-2\zeta(n+z+1)+\zeta(n+z+2)-\zeta(n+z+3)+\zeta(2n+z+5))\\
&=-\sum_{0<n}(\zeta(n+z+1)-1)-(\zeta(z+5)-1)\\
&=-\sum_{0<n}(\zeta(n+1)-1)+\sum_{j=1}^z(\zeta(j+1)-1)-\zeta(z+5)+1\\
&=1-\sum_{0<n}(\zeta(n+1)-1)+\sum_{j=1}^z(\zeta(j+1)-1)-\zeta(z+5)-z
\end{align}
And,
$$
\sum_{0<n}(\zeta(n+1)-1)=1
$$
is easy to show.